# How to create an Airflow task where I start a Docker container with GPU support

Tags: docker, gpu, airflow

How could I create an Airflow task where I would start a Docker container that is using GPU. When running from the terminal I would just use `--gpus all` flag. I can`t do that using DockerOperator, because it does not support device_requests parameter, which is used underneath when calling docker run with `--gpus all` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for anyone in the future - I figured it out. First, you need to mount the docker daemon socket inside an airflow docker container. Do this by changing docker-compose file by adding in the volumes section of airflow:

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Then you need to create a new docker image based on airflow docker image and install docker python SDK, eg.:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.0-python3.7

RUN pip install docker
```

then you can create tasks based on PythonOperator, where you use the docker library to create new containers. Example task (output is not pretty)

```
def start_gpu_container(**kwargs):
     client = docker.from_env()
     response = client.containers.run(
         'tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu',
         'nvidia-smi',
         device_requests=[
             docker.types.DeviceRequest(count=-1, capabilities=[['gpu']])
         ]
     )

     return str(response)
```